# How can I construct an TTransport object from InputStream in Java

Tags: java, python, inputstream, thrift

I want to rewrite a snippet of python code into java. Python code is listed below:

```
transport = StringIO(thrifts_data)        
transport.seek(0)
transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
....
doc = StreamItem()
doc.read(protocol)
```

In the above code, thrifts_data are binary streams read from files.
Now I need to rewrite it in java, I have searched on the web, but nothing useful has been found.
In java, TTransport is an abstract class and it has some subclasses, but I'm not sure which should I choose, because nobody of them contains a construct method that takes a inputstream parameter.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TIOStreamTransport` has a constructor with `InputStream` argument.

You might be also interested in `TMemoryInputTransport` and `TFileTransport`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, wildfire. I have resolved this problem the other days using TMemoryInputTransport class.

Answer (score 0):

for someone may be concerned, I have resolved the problem in java as follows:

```
TTransport transport;
transport = new TMemoryInputTransport(byte_data);
TBinaryProtocol tbp = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
StreamItem si = new StreamItem();
si.read(tbp);
```